# Is there an opening function in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm looking for an opening function for iOS, a portion of the code that initiates before the program starts running. 
If it helps i'm trying to place a block randomly on the screen BEFORE the programs starts to run, as in as soon as the program starts up the block will be placed somewhere randomly instead of its origin. The code is already typed out for that small portion, but I cannot find an openingfnc.

For those who know MatLab there was an openingfnc already built it. Sorry if i'm using the wrong terminology. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Xcode or Objective-C. What you want is something that is specific to the iOS framework.

Answer (score 6):

View will appear is called before the view is actually presented on the screen.

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    }
```

Comment: More specifically, given the requirements, this should be implemented only in the root view controller class.

Comment: Correct :-) if he/she drops it into the first view to load / root view it will work perfect.